# Python plotly. cant see the first subplot title

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, title, subplot

With that code cant see title of the first subplot. How could I fix that one? I need all the titles, but first one cant be seen.

```
amplitude1 = int(input('Amplitude 1 is '))
amplitude2 = int(input('Amplitude 2 is '))
amplitude3 = int(input('Amplitude 3 is '))
frequency1 = 1
frequency2 = 10
frequency3 = 50
sinewave = amplitude1 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * frequency1 * time + theta)

titles = (f'f1 = {frequency1} Hz, A = {amplitude1}',
    f'f2 = {frequency2} Hz, A = {amplitude2}',
    f'f3 = {frequency3} Hz, A = {amplitude3}' 
)

fig = make_subplots(
    rows=3, cols=1,
    subplot_titles=(titles)
```

[image: First title cant be seen]

Comment: What if you use `fig.update_layout` to increase the height of the plot?

Comment: @DerekO that wont help, height changing without titles.